# spring boot build package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit4

I am receiving below compilation error while building Spring Boot application in a build env. However I don't see any error while running Junit test or building(package) it locally on my machine  -

> src/main/java/com/abc/tests/AbcTest.java :   package org.junit does
>   not exist

Here is my pom.xml -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependencies>........
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here are the Steps i tried with no success - 
1. placing explicit dependency on junit 4.12 as well as [4.12] in dependency section.

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>junit</groupId>
>     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>     <version>4.12</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>  
> </dependency>
> ```

2. adding maven-surefire-plugin with and without version 2.18.1 of plugin

> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>         <junitArtifactName> junit:junit:4.12</junitArtifactName>
>     </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

Is there any other way to force the build process to use 4.12 junit version within pom.xml instead of picking some old version like 3.8 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have put your test inside the `main/java` instead of `test/java`: `src/main/java/com/abc/tests/AbcTest.java`

The Junit dependency has the `<scope>test</scope>` so it is only visible to sources inside the `test/java` during the build time.

Comment: should he not put the tests to `test/java` instead of `main/java`? Then the scope can be test.

Comment: he should put them in test/java. Unless he overrides the maven-surefire-plugin defaults which is not recommended

Comment: Above is right solution! i was fully aware  and had it correctly in my project but someone checked in a test class under main and i overlooked path even while posting this question !