# java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist and java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist errors in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

I get these two errors

> java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist

and

> java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist

When I try to run my Spring project. This project was developed on Windows before, and I have exported it to git. Now, I'm working on a Mac and the problem is that I've installed the entire environment correctly, but still getting the same error.

I tried manually adding  these 2 dependencies in pom.xml and reloading the Maven project, but this didn't work.

This is the pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.catacoman</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>Simple API related to movies</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <!-- JUnit 5 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version> <!-- You can specify a different version if needed -->
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Boot Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Show the full pom file...

Comment: added it to the problem description @khmarbaise

Comment: Are the classes producing these errors in `src/main/java` instead of `src/test/java`?

Comment: Remove the version number from junit-jupiter-api because it's already defined by the parent... and also check the location of your files.. as @MarkRotteveel asked..

Comment: the error is being produced by src/test/java, I also tried removing version number from junit-juniper-api and its still not working

Comment: can you check if the lombok jar is installed on the Mac? and see if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170584/spring-boot-build-package-org-junit-does-not-exist#:~:text=You%20have%20put,the%20build%20time.)

Comment: still not working, i will try to rewrite the entire project from scratch because i just lose time with this. thanks guys for the help

Comment: Have you tried to build on plain command and **NOT** from within your IDE ?